# getting roll and pitch angle from pixel change

Tags: python

"I am trying to write image-based guidance for my unmanned aerial vehicle. My image detection and tracking algorithms are working, but in order to follow the vehicle in front of me, I need to get the roll pitch angle based on the pixel change caused by its movement. How can I do this conversion?
"

```
def convert_pixel_to_angle(x, y, image_width, image_height, fov_width, fov_height):
    center_x = image_width / 2
    center_y = image_height / 2
    dx = x - center_x
    dy = y - center_y
    angle_x = (dx / image_width) * 2 * fov_width
    angle_y = (dy / image_height) * 2 * fov_height
    return angle_x, angle_y;
```

"It will be something like this, but the entire code also includes the Kalman filter and other different algorithms. I just want to get the pitch and roll angle of the vehicle I am following in front of me according to the pixel change in the image."